# File Upload with Array not working

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to upload multiple files as an array but getting error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
```

My code is the following:

**PHP**

```
  foreach ($_FILES as $file) {  
     $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
     $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
     $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
     $folder="../../uploads/";
     $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file); }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="field"><label for="file_01">file_01</label><input type="file" name="file[]" multiple></div>
<div class="field"><label for="file_01">file_01</label><input type="file" name="file[]" multiple></div>
<div class="field"><label for="file_01">file_01</label><input type="file" name="file[]" multiple></div>
```

How I can fix that error ? any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loading the entire array to $file_loc (iterating incorrectly) :

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($_FILES['file']['name']);$i++) {
    if($_FILES['error'][$i] === 0) { //checks that a file was uploaded without error on current index
        $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
        $folder="../../uploads/";
        $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file);
    }
}
```

Whenever you have a problem like this in the future, remember that you can use:

```
print_r($_FILES); //in any case with an array
```

To see how the array is structured. That's how I found out that you were iterating it incorrectly. The output from this looks like:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => upnp_trace4.log
                    [1] => upnp_trace2.log
                    [2] => upnp_trace1.log
                )
            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => text/x-log
                    [1] => text/x-log
                    [2] => text/x-log
                )
            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phps82zof
                    [1] => /tmp/phpcq2oiG
                    [2] => /tmp/phpA2mec7
                )
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )
            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9
                    [1] => 9
                    [2] => 9
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: I kinda like this looping method better. That way, there's no need to manually add array numbers should extra ones be added on later and dynamically. By the way, I'm "not" the OP here ;-)

Comment: I prefer this answer than mine as well :) More reliable !

Answer (score 1):

This may be due because your input files have the same name (name="file[]"). That creates an array.

So you may need to do that :

```
 //first file
 $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($file_loc[0],$folder.$final_file);
 //second file
 $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($file_loc[1],$folder.$final_file);
 //third file
 $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($file_loc[2],$folder.$final_file);
```

do not forget to check if there is three files that are being uploaded or not.